# Reading in line from txt file in python

Tags: python, file, text

I'm having trouble it seems with reading in lines from a text file.  When I do the whole f.readline() I can save it to a string and then print off the correct text however when lets say I go to print the first or second character of the string I just made it'll print a strange like dot checker pattern character instead of the correct letter.

Edit: Ok so when I try alfasin's method I seem to get the correct length of each line besides the first line that is read in.  If I'm say reading in 5 lines and looking for a space, the first line with find the first space at spot 13 when it should find it at spot 8.  However the next lines read in will all produce the correct length and location of the space.

Edit2: Also the text file I am reading in is UTF-8.

Edit3: Definitely was an issue with the encoding of the text file.  I changed it to ANSI and everything started working as it should.

Comment: What is the encoding of the file? (UTF-8, etc)

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
with open('filename.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        print line
        # and if you want to break it down to characters:
        print list(line)
```